# не могу установить requests в приложение. Как быть?

Tags: python, django

Вот подтверждение что он есть

```css
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corp.), 2009. Все права защищены.

C:\Python37>python
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
>>> import requests3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests3'
>>> quit()

C:\Python37>pip install requests3
Requirement already satisfied: requests3 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (0.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: h11 in c:\python37\lib\site-packages (from requests3) (0.8.1)

C:\Python37>
```

Но при этом при импорте в приложение выдает ошибку

```css
   from . import views
  File "F:\project\WeatherApp\weather\views.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests3'
```

во views.py в шапку поставил строку 
import requests (пробовал requests3 - толку нет)
Примечание: Python 3.7 стоит на диске С(где и винда). Приложение на другом диске - в него и пытаюсь поставить во views.py import requests

Вот результат по запросам

```css
>>> import sys
>>> print('\n'.join(sys.path))

C:\Python37\python37.zip
C:\Python37\DLLs
C:\Python37\lib
C:\Python37
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages
>>> sys.path.append("c:\python37\lib")
>>> import request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'request'
```

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, при установке Python пропустили пункт "Add Python to the Windows Path"

Чтобы это проверить, в командной строке наберите

```
import sys
print('\n'.join(sys.path))
```

А потом добавьте путь и проверьте, импортируется библиотека либо нет

```
sys.path.append("c:\python37\lib")

import request
```

Comment: да все так и есть... Выше результат. Подскажите пожалуйста как лечить ??

Comment: Path\easy_install.exe requests не помогает. Выдает ошибку по синтаксису жалуется на букву s в конце слова requests

Comment: Оригинальный (не фейковый) requests можно скачать https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/index.html  в виде файла *.whl
И установить WHL 
pip install some-package.whl

Честное слово. Я исхожу из того, что у Вас, Дмитрий, все в порядке с путями PATH и Вы внимательно, неторопясь можете запускать скрипт из любого нужного каталога.

Comment: How do I find the location of my Python site-packages directory? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory

Comment: пляски продолжаются - куда установил requests3 не понятно. В проекте так же установить не могу...

Comment: вот это помогло python -m pip install requests

Answer (score 0):

вот что помогло.
Найдите ваш python и найдите каталог Scripts. Откройте cmd, перейдите в эту папку и введите pip install requests.

Answer (score 0):

вы походу устанавливаете requests на второй питон,
в след. раз давайте сразу с выбором версии питона устанавливать модули

`python3 -m pip install requests`